# Failed checkout

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a problem for checkout my project in my windows (it's working on ubuntu).
When I enter my URL in a navigator (chrome) I have the list of elements on my SVN project.
But when I want checkout my project with TortoiseSVN my authentification failed (it's working with chrome with the same authentification) :

```
Checkout from https://XXXX/svn/project, revision HEAD, Fully recursive, Externals included
Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://XXXX/svn/project'
Access to 'X/svn/project' forbidden
```

Do you have any idea what this could be ?

Comment: Are you sure authentication failed? It says "forbidden"...

Comment: Yes he says that my access is forbidden but when I want to access this by chrome there is no problem... and by ubuntu same thing...

Comment: I can't understand... How can you check out from a Subversion repository using Chrome? Are you using an extension?

Comment: No I haven't checkout my project with chrome I access just to repository. It's the proof that I arrived to access this project. My problem is : I want to checkout my project with tortoiseSVN but he failed. I suppose the problem is tortoiseSVN because it's impossible to access repository with him.

Comment: The checkout failed with Eclipse (on Windows) to...  But it's working with Netbeans on Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the only error wording you are getting, then the problem is with *authorization*, not *authentication*. You authenticate successfully, but your user account lacks necessary permissions to read `https://XXXX/svn/project`.

You should make sure that you enter valid and correct URL to the repository or repository subtree and ensure that you have at least Read Only access to the repository or its subtree.

And it always makes sense to double-check that you run an up-to-date Subversion client software. Use Subversion 1.9.

Comment: I use the version 1.9.3. I have authorization because it's possible for me to checkout the project on ubuntu with exactly the same URL